# glCompressedTexImage2D for rectangular texture

Tags: opengl

it seems `glCompressedTexImage2D` does not handle `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE`..

I am trying to load Valve's VTF texture file, and most of them seems to be rectangular with DXT1 compression.

how do I work around this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the obvious thing: stop using [rectangle textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rectangle_Texture) for them. Regular textures can be rectangular.

The only reason to use rectangle textures is because you want to [sample from them with non-normalized texture coordinates](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rectangle_Texture#Use_in_shaders).

Comment: actually after further investigation they aren't rectangular texture... they are indeed pow of two... thanks anyway